# How do I make a vbs script to move a certain file to the desktop if I click on it?

Tags: vbscript, file-move

There is a folder in which I have a file, and a shortcut to that file.

I need a VBscript in the same folder which will move the shortcut to the desktop.

If there is any more information you require to help me, I will give it to you.

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: We are not here to implement your requirements. You know what you have to do, so do it. There is official documentation on the MSDN and countless examples of file handling all over the internet. Read them, try it yourself and come back when you are *actually* stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works for me...

```
Dim ObjFso 
Dim SourceLocation 
Dim DestinationLocation 
Dim FileName  

SourceLocation = "C:\REST-OF-PATH"
DestinationLocation = "%userprofile%\Desktop\" 
FileName = "FILENAME"

Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
ObjFso.MoveFile SourceLocation & "" & FileName, DestinationLocation & ""
```

Just copy all this...

Then replace `REST-OF-PATH`with the rest of the path

And Replace `FILENAME` with the name of the file

Comment: You really should use `ObjFso.BuildPath()` to construct paths, instead of `&`.